# Assign dynamic variable to style-loader path

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am trying to load css file based on variable using:

```
require('style-loader!../custom2.css')
```

Here I want to use 'custom2' as variable i.e

```
const path='custom2';
require('style-loader!../'+ path +'.css')
```

This is not working, Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed quote characters.

Try with:

```
require('styleloader!../'+ path +'.css')
```

Or ES6 template string:

```
require(`styleloader!../${path}.css`)
```

Comment: Sorry!! that was my mistake. quote were correct as shown (I have updated the question)

Comment: I am using angular-cli and the solution you mentioned won't work properly for me

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/css/font-awesome.min.css.   Encountered this issue with minified css on command prompt